# How to reset inputs in python?

Tags: python, input

How do you reset inputs?
Let's say the code is:

```
input_x = raw_input("insert #")
print input_x + 1
print input_x
```

and when the third line is executed I want it to say `insert #` so that it's a loop.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a while loop:

```
while True:
    input_x = int(raw_input("insert # or 0 to quit"))
    if input_x == 0: # break loop if user enters 0
        print "Goodbye"
        break
    print input_x + 1
    print input_x
```

Use `int(raw_input("insert #"))` to convert the string to an integer presuming you are only inputting `ints` which makes sense as you are adding `1` to each inputted value, `raw_input` returns a `string` so if you input `123` without casting to `int` it is a  string `'123'`

The loop will keep repeating unless we add a `break` condition so when the user enters `0` we will leave our loop.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
while True:
    input_x = raw_input("insert #")
    print int(input_x) + 1
    print input_x
```

Of course, this will be an infinite loop, so if you run this program in your terminal, exit it by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> once you have enough of it. (Or implement a `break` somewhere in your loop.)

You also have to pay attention to the following: the input from `raw_input` will be of type `string`. So you will either have to type cast `input_x` to type `int`, or type cast the `+ 1` to `+ str(1)` (this will result in whatever you input plus the character `'1'`, e.g. if your input is `abc`, `print input_x + str(1)` will print `abc1`).

Answer (score 0):

Use a while

```
while True:    # infinite loop
    input_x = raw_input("insert #")
    print input_x + 1
    print input_x
    if some_condition: #you should put some_condition for break the loop
        #because it will be an infinite loop
        break #break the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
     input_x = raw_input("insert a number or write 'end' to exit: ")
     if input_x=='end': break
     print int(input_x) + 1
     print input_x
```